# count keywords in structure

Tags: c, structure

[Program from K&R Book]

This is program to count words. I want to ask why this program has passed `word` as the first argument of the fucntion `getword` in line 12  instead of `*word`. `Word` would get the address of the first element of the array. While `*word` would get the value. So, shouldn't we pass `*word` instead of just `word`. I guess i am asking wrong question because `getword` should return an `int` and their is no way its returning `int` if its not the address of the first position. I still doubt it. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define MAXWORD 100 
int getword(char *, int); 
int binsearch(char *, struct key*, int); 
/* count C keywords */ 

main() 
{ 
  int n; 
  char word[MAXWORD]; 
  while (getword(word, MAXWORD)  !=  EOF)    <<<<<<<-------HERE------->>>>>>>
      if (isalpha(word[O])) 
         if ((n = binsearch(word, keytab, NKEYS)) >=  0) 
             keytab[n].count++; 
  for (n = 0; n  < NKEYS; n++) 
      if (keytab[n].count > 0) 
         printf( "%4d %s\n", keytab[n].count, keytab[n].word); 
  return 0; 
}
```

code for getword:

```
int qetword(char *word,  int lim) 
{ 
  int c, qetch(void); 
  void unqetch(int); 
  char *W  = word; 
  while (isspace(c = qetch()))
    ; 
  if (c  I=  EOF) 
    *W++  = c; 
  if (lisalpha(c)) { 
    *W  = '\0'; 
    return c; 
  } 
  for (  ;  --lim > 0; W++) 
    if ( lisalnum(*W = getch())) { 
      unqetch ( *W) ; 
      break; 
    } 
  *W  = '\0'; 
  return word[O]; 
}
```

Comment: Since `word` is a pointer to a character, `*w` is just a *single character*. That's not what you want.

Comment: `int c, qetch(void);` is The Devil.

Comment: You have horrible typos: `qetch` is not `getch` and `unqetch` is not `ungetch`. and of course `qetword` is not `getword`.

Comment: I have copy pasted this from pdf file sorry didn't knew this would go wrong @Elazar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an array of `char` in an expression, it decays into `char*`. Passing it to a function is an example of such a usage.

Since the function being called, `getword`, expects a `char*` as argument, using a variable that is declared as an array of `char` is appropriate.

When you declare:

```
char word[MAXWORD];
```

`*word` evaluates to a `char`, specifically the first character of the array, not a `char*`.

Comment: "When you use an array of `char` as an expression it decays into `char*`" would be more general, and will automatically explain your last sentence.